Vercel Deployment Error: RollupError: Could not resolve 'foo/path'
I want to deploy a vite javascript react app on vercel
Everything seemed fine until a few commits later I got this error on vercel:
enter image description here
Everything is working fine on localhost.
After changing the folder structure, trying everything, redeploying, and more, I'm still getting the same error.
